# Issues: Deploy freeze in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, freeze, cicd

I attempted to establish a freeze period starting at * 9 * * FRI and ending at * 9 * * MON in GITLAB UI, with the intention of preventing any team member from initiating and executing the pipeline on those specific days.

I anticipated that the pipeline would refrain from running on the designated days. However, the pipeline is still permitted to execute during these days. I also included the following lines in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

`workflow: rules: - if: $CI_DEPLOY_FREEZE == null`

And these commands seem to prevent the pipeline from running on all days, rather than just the designated freeze periods. Also, I attempted to print the value of $CI_DEPLOY_FREEZE and noticed that it consistently returns "True" both during freeze periods and non-freeze periods.

I'm struggling to identify the cause of this issue, and I'm uncertain whether I might be overlooking or misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this cron:

```
start: 0 9 * * FRI
end: 0 9 * * MON
```

This means start freeze "at 09:00 on Friday", end freeze "at 09:00 on Monday".

Your `* 9 * * FRI` means start freeze "at every minute past hour 9 on Friday." So the freeze starts in every minute after 9 on Friday, even after 09:00 Monday.